# API which waits for a message using Spring-Kafka

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I'm using Spring Boot 2.0.7 and Spring-Kafka to create a request/reply pattern. Basically the frontend UI makes a request to an API which puts a message on to a request Kafka queue, the message is processed by a backend process and when complete a message is put onto a reply queue.

I want to provide the frontend UI an api which waits until the response is ready. The UI in this time will just show a processing message. If the response is not available (e.g. after 2 minutes), the API should just return a message not available error where we can instruct the user to come back later.

I'm a bit new to Spring-Kafka. Does it allow me to create a polling API? If so, any example code would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It's not as simple as polling a topic for a reply because you have to correlate requests/replies.

You can use `ReplyingKafkaTemplate.sendAndReceive()` and keep checking the `isDone()` method on the `Future<?>`.

If you want to poll yourself, you would have to create a consumer object from the consumer factory.

Comment: Thanks Gary, the user id is the correlation. I’ll try to use the above api to see if I can get it to work.